# Proving that lower limit topology is not second countable

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm studying Foundations of Topology by C. Wayne Patty. The author asks this question as an exercise. So

Here's my attempt:

Let $\mathscr{B}=\{ B_n : n\in \mathbb N\}$ be countable basis for the lower limit topology.   Assume that $B_n\ne B_m$ and $B_m \ne \emptyset$ for each $m,n$ with $m\ne n$. Since each $B_n$ is uncountable, we can select points $x_k$ satisfying $x_k\in B_k$ for each $k$ and $x_m\ne x_n$ for each $m\ne n$.

We may assume $x_m<x_n$ for $m  <n$ by relabeling if necessary. Now for each $i$, we can select points $a_i, b_i$ such that $x_i<a_i<b_i<x_{i+1}$. Now consider the set $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb N} [a_i, b_{i})$. Since $\mathscr{B}=\{ B_n : n\in \mathbb N\}$ is a basis for lower limit topology, there must be some subset $A$ of $\mathbb N$ such that
$$\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb N} [a_i, b_{i})=\bigcup_{ k\in A} B_k$$
Let $k\in A$. Then $x_k\in B_k$, so, $x_k\in[a_i, b_{i})$ for some $i$.

But this is not possible as $x_k \not \in [a_i, b_i)$ for any $i$.

---

Is this proof correct? Do not mark this as duplicate as I only seek proof verification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m afraid that this won’t work. It might happen, for instance, that the points $x_n\in B_n$ are the entire set of rational numbers; then there is no way to re-index them by the natural numbers so that $x_m<x_n$ whenever $m<n$.

You could also notice that if this argument *were* valid, you could make the essentially the same argument for the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. The only change would be that you would consider the set $\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}(a_i,b_i)$ instead of $\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}[a_i,b_i)$, and by the same reasoning you would arrive at the clearly false conclusion that the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ is not second countable.

You really do have to make use of the fact that each $x\in\Bbb R$ has a base of nbhds of the form $[x,y)$ with $y>x$. A straightforward way to do that is to argue that if your $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the lower-limit topology, then for each $x\in\Bbb R$ there must be an $n(x)\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\in B_{n(x)}\subseteq[x,x+1)$. $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, and $\Bbb N$ is only countable, so there must be distinct $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $n(x)=n(y)$. But then

$$x\in B_{n(x)}=B_{n(y)}\subseteq[y,y+1)\,,$$

so that $x\ge y$, and

$$y\in B_{n(y)}=B_{n(x)}\subseteq[x,x+1)\,,$$

so that $y\ge x$, and hence $x=y$, contradicting the distinctness of $x$ and $y$. This contradiction shows that the lower-limit topology on $\Bbb R$ does not have a countable base.

This argument uses an infinite form of the pigeonhole principle, taking advantage of the fact that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable. And that uncountability matters, because it turns out that the lower limit topology on the countable set $\Bbb Q$ **is** second countable. (In fact, $\Bbb Q$ with its lower limit topology is actually homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, though that fact is by no means trivial to prove.)